# grammar problem on FAQ

Tags: bug, status-completed

There is repetition here:

> The Geographic Information Systems Stack Exchange is for **is for** questions concerning geographic information systems and science.

Comment: Analytical Badge = Visited every section of the FAQ..117 Users earned this badge and didn't see it :-)

Answer (score 1):

Thank you--that has been fixed now.